# Div inside how to call class in css?

Tags: html, css

I have mentioned the code below.

Need Output:when you click on check box don't display(Hide) the tr class="invalid" columns.If you unchecked display the all the tr columns.

Any solution is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the adjacent selector to make it work:

```
#testday input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #testtable .invalid {
    display:none;
}
```

snippet below:

```css
#testday input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #testtable .invalid {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="testday">
  <input type="checkbox" checked><span class="invalid black-border">Tests not in POR</span>
  <table id="testtable" class="tablesorter custom-popup">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-priority="critical" class="testName">Test Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="invalid">
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="BasicPerformanceMatrixTest">BasicPerformanceMatrixTest</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="invalid">
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="StripeReadECCFatalDuringPLIRestore_NSGSE-23331">StripeReadECCFatalDuringPLIRestore_NSGSE-23331</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="invalid">
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="ContextReplayTimes_NSGSE-27617">ContextReplayTimes_NSGSE-27617</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr class="invalid">
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="XORRecoveryShouldSkipRetiredPages_NSGSE-27131">XORRecoveryShouldSkipRetiredPages_NSGSE-27131</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="PliDumpECCFatal(XOROn_2Codewords)[unaligned]_NSGSE-22801">PliDumpECCFatal(XOROn_2Codewords)[unaligned]_NSGSE-22801</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="PliDumpECCFatal(XOROff_2Codewords)[unaligned]_NSGSE-22802">PliDumpECCFatal(XOROff_2Codewords)[unaligned]_NSGSE-22802</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="PliDumpECCFatal(XOROff_1Page)_NSGSE-22803">PliDumpECCFatal(XOROff_1Page)_NSGSE-22803</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="testName">
          <abbr title="PLIECCFatal(SuperXORtest)_NSGSE-23162">PLIECCFatal(SuperXORtest)_NSGSE-23162</abbr>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/prfoc9hh/6/)

css

Use general sibling selector `~`
It seperates two selectors and matches the second element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common parent.

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ table .invalid {
     display:none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #testtable .invalid {
   display:none;
}
```

Would be the easiest way.